# jenkins war file not deploying on glassfish

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to build and deploy a war file by jenkins to payara server.

Status:
Build-success
Deploy war/ear to a container-Failure, but the war file deployed in payara server and it is disabled.

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Console Log:

```
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: Deployment has failed: null
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractJsr88Deployer.waitForProgressObject(AbstractJsr88Deployer.java:295)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractJsr88Deployer.deploy(AbstractJsr88Deployer.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractJsr88Deployer.redeploy(AbstractJsr88Deployer.java:217)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:147)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:117)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1020)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:998)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:114)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeploy(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:93)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:64)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1752)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
```

Comment: Try to remove all deployed applications from the glassfish, restart the glasfish and run your build again

Comment: i have tried but its not working.